# URL to Wordpress Post Thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

POST ID: 1
My Image URL: site.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb/1.jpg

How can I visually adjust this to WordPress?

set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id ); Can I do it with? I just want to set the URL in the dimension does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this method.

If the image is already uploaded in the WP media library, you just need to get that image ID from the admin panel(Have a look at the URL of the image details to get it). And then pass that ID as a 2nd parameter of this function [set_post_thumbnail()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail)

If you want to upload an image from a URL to WP media library, you also can do that and then pass that image ID to this function set_post_thumbnail(). Please check this [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40301/how-do-i-set-a-featured-image-thumbnail-by-image-url-when-using-wp-insert-post)

Please be aware about the WP version for function usage.